Ceiling fan/light not receiving signal after replacing battery in the remote
Vento ceiling fan/light no longer receiving signal from the remote after replacing the battery. The led light comes on when trying to operate the fan but with no luck. I have turned off the power supply but to no avail. Remote #3810230570. I'm really hoping you can advise me of my next steps.
Kind rgards
Frustrated John.

Make/model of fan? Was it working before replacing the battery? If it was, just intermittent or limited range (which would be typical for a low battery) then there may be a "pairing" procedure or other steps needed. If it was not working before changing the battery then it could be that the problem is in the receiver attached to the fan and not in the transmitter (remote)?
